# Identify top scorers

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
People A B C D 
Score  3 4 4 1
```

Based on data above, I am using the formula below to identify the top scorer in the list.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$5,MATCH(MAX($B$2:$B$5),$B$2:$B$5,0))
```

The result is **Person B**

However, the issue is Person C has the same score of 4 as 1 of the highest other than B.

How can I modify the formula to have both Person appear in separate cell as 2 highest scorers?

Comment: Do you want the names to appear across a row or down a column?

Answer (score 1):

With data like:

[image]

We will use row **#3** as a helper row.  In **A3** enter:

```
=IF(A2=MAX(2:2),1,"")
```

and in **B3** enter:

```
=IF(B2=MAX(2:2),1+MAX($A3:A$3),"")
```

and copy across. *(row #3 marks the winners)*.  Finally in **A4** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(1:1,MATCH(COLUMN(),3:3,0)),"")
```

and copy across:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What about Albert who scored as 3rd Highest in this case? How should I make his ranking appear in Row 3 as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one formula:

```
=IF(ROW(1:1)<=COUNTIF(B:B,MAX(B:B)), INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$5)/($B$2:$B$5=MAX(B:B)),MIN(ROW(1:1),COUNTIF(B:B,MAX(B:B))))),"")
```

Put in a cell then drag/copy down.

[image]

If your data is in rows instead of columns, change all the `ROW` to `COLUMN` and all the full column references to full row references and vice versa.

Comment: What if the Score value is changing from time to time and I need it to be automated identifying the Top 3 scorer, put in mind that some may have same highest score just like the above?

Comment: New Question = New Post @J.Tan